# Run PowerShell script with admin privileges and bypass execution policy

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble with PowerShell script. I'm getting an error when running it

> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
>   For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
>   https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

Script is not being run as admin.

```
if (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
    $arguments = "& '" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "'"
    Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
    break
}

Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force

# Rest code
```

Seems like the line with execution policy is not being executed.

The command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

didn't help as well.

Comment: You cannot bypass the execution policy from inside a script. You cannot run this script because of the execution policy. You can call the Powershell executable with the according parameter like this: `Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "Your file name here"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ExecutionPolicy is keeping the script from running at all. You will have to call the .ps1 with parameters that deal with that up front.

Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File yourscript.ps1

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this.   I have found that if I type in the double quotes in the task schedule action tab, it will work.  If you copy and paste, the double quote is different and does not work.   If you type a quote in Word for example, it looks like this  “, if you type it in Task Scheduler it looks like this  ".   Same exact key on the keyboard, but apparently different ascii code and it does not work when you copy and paste.

Comment: It should be self-evident that Microsoft Word is not a programming environment.

Comment: This may be a problem, but does not appear to be OP's problem - see user Olaf's comment.